# Google Text To Speak giving 503 error

Tags: java

I'm using Google Text to speech to convert my string value. Below is my test code

```
Translator translate1 = Translator.getInstance();
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
String text = translate1.translate("hello", Language.ENGLISH, Language.PORTUGUESE); 
System.out.println(text);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=t&text=hello&hl=en&sl=en&tl=pt&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve your question, can you describe how you've investigated so far into what is going wrong; for example, have you looked up how and why the server might return a 503 response code?

Comment: Yes i have. The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay.Some servers may wish to simply refuse the connection. But Im not sure whats happening in my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?